# How to create 2 query options inside an IF function in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create an if function and if true execute one query if false execute another query, but I keep on having a 'Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows' error, the funtion goes like this:

=ARRAYFORMULA({"Cases";IF(H2="SFDC",QUERY(OPTION1),QUERY(OPTION2))})

Any ideia why, is there any other way to construct a conditional like this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Since the error msg is from your particular sheet, you should share a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) where you encounter the error.

Comment: @jesus-navarro Include your example to get accurate answers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that our output as the same number of columns. For example, in your equation, you have one column of data (the header `"Cases"`). Because of this, the result of your `IF` statement must also have only one column of data.

One way to fix this is to define some extra empty columns. For example:
`=ARRAYFORMULA({"Cases","","";IF(H2="SFDC",QUERY({1,2,3},"select *"),QUERY({4,5,6},"select *"))})`
[image: ex]

I added two more columns after `Cases`, therefore allowing my resulting query to properly expand.

Answer (score 0):

This error is produced When two arrays have different numbers of columns, in you case make sure the length of array in `QUERY(OPTION1)` is the same length as
the one in `QUERY(OPTION2)`.
use this formula to check array length.
for `QUERY(OPTION1)`

```
=COUNTA(SPLIT(QUERY(OPTION1),"/"))
```

and this for `QUERY(OPTION2)`

```
=COUNTA(SPLIT(QUERY(OPTION2),"/"))
```

Replace it with your formula of course.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue, I was not specifying the header at the end of the query which was generating a conflict.
Thanks to all.